# deploy application on jboss

Tags: web-applications, jboss

My question has not got to do with jBPM it's only an example.

I started my jboss on port 8080 and when I go to `http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/` I see a live application.

However, under server/default/deploy I don't see any `jbpm-console` folder!

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be in a `war` file (file or exploded war). If you have any, the `jbpm-console` should be defined in a `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` file as `<context-root>jbpm-console</context-root>`

More info [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/ch9.chapt.html), more precisely Chapter 9.5.: Setting the context root of a web application